# how to add React ToolKit Query to existing app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-query

I have a website that is using react redux toolkit, but now I want to migrate it to RTK query, because it has some options like caching, etc, so, I have this endpoint:
/products, that is returning this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "T-shirt z",
    "price": 15.09,
    "description": "",
    "imageURL": "https://live.staticflickr.com/7013/6612824761_3f66a93c71_b.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "T-shirt x",
    "price": 25.99,
    "description": "",
    "imageURL": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0386/0293/2356/products/image_2c5617fb-89a7-4d04-9bfb-f0c0dcd28f6d_590x.jpg?v=1612476249"
  },
  ...
  ....
]
```

api/products.ts

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import type { Product } from "../app/api";

export interface ProductsState {
  products: { [id: string]: Product };
}

///and also I don't know how to set the initial state
const initialState: ProductsState = {
  products: {},
}; 

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const productsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "productsApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProducts: builder.query<Product[], string>({
      query: () => "/products",
      transformResponse: (response: Product[]) : ProductsState => // here is an error
        {          
          return {
            products: response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
              acc[curr.id] = curr; // here is an error
              return acc;
            }, {});
          }
        }
    }),
  }),
});
```

app/api.ts

```
export interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  imageURL: string;
}

....
...
```

I want to transform the result of the api, to this:

```
 {
    products:{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "T-shirt z",
        "price": 15.09,
        "description": "",
        "imageURL": "https://live.staticflickr.com/7013/6612824761_3f66a93c71_b.jpg"
      },
    "2":{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "T-shirt x",
        "price": 25.99,
        "description": "",
        "imageURL": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0386/0293/2356/products/image_2c5617fb-89a7-4d04-9bfb-f0c0dcd28f6d_590x.jpg?v=1612476249"
      }
    }
    }
```

In the transformResponse method I get this typescript error:

> ```
> Type '(response: Product[]) => ProductsState' is not assignable to type '(baseQueryReturnValue: unknown, meta: FetchBaseQueryMeta |
> ```
>
> undefined, arg: string) => Product[] | Promise<Product[]>'.
> Type 'ProductsState' is not assignable to type 'Product[] | Promise<Product[]>'.ts(2322)
> endpointDefinitions.d.ts(41, 5): The expected type comes from property 'transformResponse' which is declared here on type
> 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<string, BaseQueryFn<string |
> FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>,
> Product[]> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>, "type"> |
> Omit<...>'

and here **acc[curr.id]** , I get this typescript error:

> (parameter) curr: Product Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
> expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.   No
> index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

What can I do? thank you.